# react: why does the onclick get executed even without having clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Warning: Severe React beginner.

I have a class:

```
 export default class ItemsView extends React.Component {

    //...

    render() { 
      return (
        <div>
           <Container>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                 <ul style={{listStyleType:"none"}}>
                   {   
                     this.state.items.map((item) => {
                     return <li key={item.number} style={{cursor: "pointer"}}><Item onClick={this.handleSelected(item)} value={item.timestamp}/></li>
                     })  
                   }   
                 </ul>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                <ItemDetail item={this.selected} />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Container>

          </div>
      )
   }
}

handleSelected(item) {
   console.log("handle");
   this.selected = item;
 }
```

What I want is that when I click on the `Item` div, which is rendered dynamically as a list of elements, the details of the item would appear in the `ItemDetails` component.

Apart from the fact that probably my design isn't really "React"y, why does the `handleSelected` get called when iterating, and not when I click on it?

Comment: you're executing the function with `this.handleSelected(item)`, you should pass in a function like `() => this.handleSelected(item)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are invoking the function rather than passing a function reference to be executed on click. You should either define the handler to return a function or use a lambda / fat arrow function in the click handler

```
onClick={() => this.handleSelected(item)}
```

remember, `this.handleSelected` is the functions reference. `this.handleSelected()` is the return value of an already invoked function.

Comment: Code only answers aren't the best idea. An explanation of *why* your proposed code works would be much better and help future readers.

Comment: @BrianThompson I helped him out :)

Comment: This answers my question, thus I am gonna accept this one. @JohnRuddell 's extended answer was very helpful though to understand what I have to do!

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the answer Vincenzo posted, you need to also use component state here. A handler that updates a property on the class will not result in a new render cycle. I can see that you are using `this.selected` in the render as a prop to `ItemDetail`

```
<ItemDetail item={this.selected} />
```

This is problematic as changing the value of `this.selected` will not trigger a new render. This is a great use case to use component state

```
export default class ItemsView extends React.Component {
    state = { selected: null, items: [] }
    handleSelected = (selected) => (event) => {
// ----------------------^------------^----
// return a function in the handler to pass a callback to the click handler
      console.log("handle");
      this.setState({ selected });
// -----------^------------^----
// set the selected item on component state when clicked
    }

    //...

    render() { 
      return (
        <div>
           <Container>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                 <ul style={{listStyleType:"none"}}>
                   { this.state.items.map((item) => <li key={item.number} style={{cursor: "pointer"}}>
                       <Item onClick={this.handleSelected(item)} value={item.timestamp}/>
// --------------------------------------------^---------------
// no change necessary here since the handler returns a function.
                     </li>
                   )}   
                 </ul>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                <ItemDetail item={this.state.selected} />
// --------------------------------------^---------------
// reference state here
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Container>

          </div>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer, it brought me further on the wider issue....:)

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping over a list of items and want to pass the item to a handler callback (`handleSelected` in this case). You usually would pass that through by invoking the function with parenthesis `()`. However, the side effect of this is the function is immediately executed. To fix that you can place it inside an arrow function, allowing it to execute on the click instead.

Hence: `onClick={() => this.handleSelected(item)}`